# uable to profile with oprofile

Tags: c++, eclipse, oprofile

I am using cent os 5.5 .

Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.18-164.el5xen #1 SMP Thu Sep 3 04:03:03 EDT 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I am trying to profile my project(server) with oprofile written in c++.

So, for that i am using eclipse Helios Service Release 2 and it has a plugin for oprofile. I have installed the plugin through eclipse. but when i try to profile with oprofile a message bos pop up saying that,

"An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError"

I have also tried with eclipse plugin gprof. It creates the gmon.out file but unfortunately it did not take any sample. It can only show the number of times qa function is called but it couldnt show the duration of time a function executes. Can pls anyone tell me why this is happening ?

can anyone tell me if cent os kernel support profiling with oprofile.

My project is a server written in c++. It has shared libraries and it is multithreaded.It is not much efficient. So i am trying to find out where it is spending much time and where it is overloading the cpu.

It would be a gr8 help if anyone can tell me how i can profile my server with oprofile or gprof in eclipse in a proper way.I am prefering eclipse because it shows the gmon.out or the output of oprofile in much more understandable way

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about gprof.
But oprofile should work on centos.
You need to make sure you have opcontrol rpm installed.
Otherwise you can get the source and build it and install it.
http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/faq/